# Same situation but different results. I think that Try syntax might be the cause

Tags: vue.js, axios

I encountered axios error in the process of creating my application.

The below code work fine.
in the first image,console.log output res.data.

```js
let categoryId = ''

axios.get('/api/max')
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data) // image part
        categoryId = res.data.id
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('ssssssuuuuu')

    })
```

('api/max') return category with max ID.

[image]

The below code don't work well.
console.log(res) output properly, but console.log(res.data) output undefined.

```js
try {
    const res = axios.get('/api/max')
    console.log(res)
    console.log(res.data) // undefined
    categoryId = res.data.id
    console.log('a')
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
}
```

[image]

what causes undefined?
I googled but, I didn't know the cause.

I'm sorry that my English is not very good.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you have around your `try catch` ? Try to wrap it into an `async` and use `await` in front of your axios get.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `await axios.get('/api/max')` before using `console.log` since it's an async call. (you can also use `.then` but it's less friendly)
Of course, don't forget to wrap your function into an `async` when using `await`.

Also, keep in mind [that quirk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects) when using `console.log`. Prefer using [Vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) to inspect the current state you do have on your page.

Overall, I recommend the usage of `async/await` over `.then` all the time.
Here is a nice documentation for that one: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: sorry for replying so late.
I did what you say and works well.

I completely thought that await keyword in front of axios is unnecessary when substituting a value for a variable.

thank you for your help!

Comment: @sorasakamoto did my answer solved your issue?

Comment: Yes! and I learned that I need to read thoroughly  promise document.
Thank you for your help!